Is a triangulated category admitting a tilting object algebraic or even equivalent to the derived category of some ring?
Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a triangulated category having all infinite coproducts(such triangulated category is sometimes said to be cocomplete or satisfying the TR5 axiom). We call an object $G$ tilting if

$G$ is compact, that is, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(G, -)$ preserves all infinite coproducts;
$G$ is a generator, that is, if $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(G, X[n])=0, \forall n\in\mathbb{Z}$, then $X=0$;
$G$ is both rigid and corigid, that is, $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{T}}(G, G[n])=0, \forall n\neq 0$.

Now suppose our triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ is cocomplete and has a tilting object $G$. I want to ask the following two questions.
Question 1: Is there a triangle equivalence between $\mathcal{T}$ and $\mathsf{D}(\mathsf{Mod}\text{-}\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{T}}(G))$?
Question 2: If the answer to the first question is false, then I wonder is $\mathcal{T}$ algebraic? By algebraic I mean $\mathcal{T}$ is triangle equivalent to the stable category of some Frobenius exact category.

Your question title says "algebraic" - I think a more common use for that term is to mean that a triangulated category is the stable category of an exact category, which is not what you're asking. I mention it because it might be that if there's a mismatch of terminology, that might not be helping your search.

@JanGrabowski Thanks a lot for your such speedy reply! And yes, the  algebraic  in my original title  Is a triangulated category admitting a tilting object algebraic?  was a mis use.

It's pretty obviously false: consider a tilting object R in the bounded below/above derived category of R.

@DenisT Thanks. These are indeed good counterexamples. But the problem is, neither the bounded above derived category nor the bounded below one has all infinite coproducts(they have some of infinite coproducts, nut not all of them). So what if I require that our triangulated category $\mathcal{T}$ has infinite coproducts, or even compactly generated with ${ T[i] | i\in\mathbb{Z} }$ a generating set of compact objects?

@ChenYifan The problem is that none of those additional assumptions are stated in your question. If you edit your question accordingly and ask exactly what you want to ask, it'll be easier to give a reasonable answer.

@DenisT Thank you for your advice. I have already re-edited the question.

Your two questions are equivalent.

Also, I think that if the answer to your question were known, it would be the topic of a paper. There are tons of extra condition ensuring that the answer is positive, though (derivators, higher categories, etc). May I ask about the motivation of your question?
